# How can I display an array of rectangles of which sizes are based on user input?

Tags: cocoa, nsmutablearray

I have read the cocoa drawing guide, read numerous blogs, etc.  I feel like I'm missing something.

Here is what I'm trying to accomplish and if you have any direction to books, blogs, tutorials, it's much appreciated!

I'm trying to draw a group of rectangles in a custom view, where the user can change the width and height of each rectangle.  When the user presses a button, the rectangle appears in the view.  They can also move the rectangles around in the custom view.  Eventually I want the user to choose the color of each, but for now, I just want to get the rectangles to draw.
What I don't understand is if I need a controller class for the array, or if the array code goes in my view controller class.  I would like to be able to have my own rectangle class to use as a model.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I would have a single controller both controlling the view (feeding it the rectangles) and owning the array of rectangles.

As for the actual drawing, [here's Apple's Cocoa Drawing Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaDrawingGuide/). There are also some [handy functions](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Miscellaneous/AppKit_Functions/Reference/reference.html%23//apple_ref/c/func/NSRectFill) for simple drawing (no gradients).